# Angular signal not updating html template

Tags: angular, signals, angular17

I have an example angular application with one service and one component:

```
Service:
export class SseService {
    private eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/events');
    private message = signal('default value');

    getMessageSignal(): Signal<string> {
      return this.message.asReadonly();
    }
 
    constructor() {
      this.eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        console.log('Received event: ', event);
        this.message.set(event.data as string);
      };
    }
}`

Component:
`@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'frontend';
    sseService = inject(SseService);
    messageSignal = this.sseService.getMessageSignal();
    // printMessage = effect(() => console.log(this.message())); //If I uncomment this line, the messageSignal does update in my html
}

<body>
    <p>{{messageSignal()}}</p>
</body>
```

The problem is, my messageSignal is not updated if I dont have the line with the effect()

Comment: Can you check is `NgZone.isInAngularZone` is true in the `onmessage` callback ?

Answer (score 1):

The EventSource callback is run in the Angular zone when you use `addEventListener` instead of `onmessage`.

```
constructor() {
  this.eventSource.addEventListener('message', () => {
    console.log('Received event: ', event);
    this.message.set(event.data as string);
  });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It´s because the `EventSource onmmessage` is outside the `NgZone`.

In your service, you should run the `NgZone` run method like this:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
  this.eventSource.onmessage = event => {
    console.log('Received event: ', event);
    ngZone.run(() => {
      this.message.set(event.data)
    })
  };
}
```

Also, you could do this:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
  this.eventSource.onmessage = event => {
    console.log('Received event: ', event);
    this.message.set(event.data)
    ngZone.run(() => {})
  };
}
```

That should do the trick. The `EventSource` is not being tracked by change detection so the `onmmessage` event occurs, you do the `console.log` and even you set the signal. But change detection is not being triggered and therefore it doesn´t update the page.

I think the issue is that the effect checks the value of the signal and in doing that check it does it inside the `ngZone` and then the other signals detect that it has changed the value and then updates.

You could have the same behavior if you put the message signal as public variable in your service and then in the component put a button with a click function that `console.log(this.message)`. That click event happens inside the `ngZone` and detects the current value of the signal and then updates the value in the page.

If you put for example in the constructor of the service the same `console.log` inside the `onmmesage` the value would not update on the page:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
  this.eventSource.onmessage = event => {
    console.log('Received event: ', event);
    this.message.set(event.data)
    console.log(this.message())
  };
}
```

but you could see in the log of your browser that in fact is updating, but outside the `ngZone`.